# Speak of the Devil

Tags: differences, word-usage, sentence

In native English people say  "Speak of the devil and he doth appear" when someone walks in unexpectedly when they are speaking about him oblivion to his appearance in a short while. But the same thing is said differently in India. We Indians take it in a positive way. We say "Let God bless him with 100 years of longevity". Why is this difference?

Is there no sentence in English that is used to bless a person instead of just scoffing at him when he arrives?

Your input is highly appreciated thanks.

Comment: I suspect it's just different culture and customs, no reason is necessary. According to wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speak_of_the_devil) the same phrase is used in Hindi as well. The only reference to "Let God bless him with 100 years of longevity" I could find on Google is this page :)

Comment: "Let ~ bless him with 100 years of longevity" and "speak of the devil" are executed under two different situations and attitudes.

Comment: Yeah you are right. It's there in Hindi as well. But my mother tongue is "Kannada". Look at "Kannada". And I beg to differ with Blessed Geek. They are executed under the same context. My question is 'why is there a difference? Devil and God are like antonyms!

Comment: You might be interested in [this question about god vs devil](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/120455/come-hell-or-high-water-vs-lord-willing-and-the-creek-dont-rise) in sayings.

Comment: I think the saying persists in modern English since it is mildly humourous to compare someone to the devil, but it does also reflect perhaps a kind of superstitious instinct to find something sinister in the coincidence, as if the person is a magical eavesdropper. Maybe you could explain why in India, there is an inclination to bless this person?

Comment: @Neil: In my opinion Indians consider it as a good omen when some one makes an appearance as one is talked about.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about cultural differences (or possibly a misunderstanding).

Comment: Hi Tim, I have posted that question keeping in mind how the same context has different takes in different countries. You may be right about cultural differences. But, it definitely relates to English usage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a complete answer as I know nothing about Hindi. But so far as English is concerned this is relevant:

The Wiki entry explains all:

> "Speak of the devil" is the short form of the idiom "Speak of the
> devil and he doth appear" (or its alternative form "speak of the devil
> and he shall appear."). It is used when an object of discussion
> unexpectedly becomes present during the conversation. It can also be
> used about a topic that quickly becomes relevant, such as the onset of
> rain or a car breaking down. Used in this sense it can be seen as an
> alternative to the phrase "tempting fate".
>
> Deriving from the Middle Ages, this proverb (which was, and to a
> certain extent still is, rendered as "Talk of the Devil...") was a
> superstitious prohibition against speaking directly of the Devil or of
> evil in general, which was considered to incite that party to appear,
> generally with unfortunate consequences. Its first printed usage in
> modern English can be found in Giovanni Torriano's Piazza Universale
> (1666), as "The English say, Talk of the Devil, and he's presently at
> your elbow."
>
> The phrase lost its overt message during the 19th century, during
> which it became a warning against eavesdroppers ("No good of himself
> does a listener hear,/Speak of the devil he's sure to appear"), and by
> the 20th century had taken on its present meaning.

However the OED quotes a reference prior to 1666 !

> l. speak or talk of the devil, and he will appear . Freq. shortened to
> talk of the devil; esp. used in reference to a person who appears
> unexpectedly when one is talking about him.
>
> [1591   J. Lyly Endimion i. iii. 3,   O that we had Sir Tophas..in the
> midst of our myrth, & ecce autem, wyl you see the deuill?]